Fourier transform of $e^{- \lvert x \rvert}$
I am asked to compute the Fourier transform of $e^{- \lvert x \rvert}$ and I've encountered a doubt. I've so far found
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}\left[ e^{ -\left| \cdot \right|  } \right] (\xi) &\equiv \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{ -\left| x \right|  } e^{ -i\xi x } \, \text{d}x  \\
&= \int_{0}^\infty e^{ - \left| x \right| - i \xi x } \, \text{d}x + \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{ -\left| x \right| - i\xi x } \, \text{d}x  \\
&= \int_{0}^\infty e^{ -(1 + i \xi) x} \, \text{d}x + \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{ (1 - i \xi) x} \, \text{d}x  \\
&= - \frac{1}{1 + i \xi} \left[ e^{ -(1 + i \xi)x } \right]_{0}^\infty + \frac{1}{1 - i \xi} \left[ e^{ (1 - i \xi)x } \right]_{-\infty}^0
\end{align}
$$
but this last line concerns me. How do I evaluate "$e^{ -(1 + i \xi)(\infty) }$"? Even if I instead consider $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{ -(1 + i \xi)x }$ the answer is not clear to me as it would depend on the "sign" of $1 + i \xi$. I've never taken complex analysis so these are foreign concepts to me.

Note that the modulus of $e^{-i\xi x}$ is $1$ and $e^{-x}\to 0$ and $x\to +\infty$

I understand that much, but where does the modulus come into play?

You're multiplying something bounded by something that goes to $0$

I see. In other words the claim is $\lim_{x \to \infty} \lvert e^{-(1 + i \xi) x} \rvert = 0$ which implies $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{-(1 + i \xi) x} = 0$?

Wolfram alpha gives $\frac{1}{\xi^2 + 1}$ up to a factor. Which is coherent with the fact that $-f''+f =\delta$ in the sense of the distributions.

Convergence in the complex plane works as you would expect it to. You are correct that the argument (i.e. the angle in the complex plane) depends on $\xi$, but in this case everything actually works out nicely. So as you would expect, for a complex-valued function $f$ defined around $0$ you have that $f(x)\to0$ as $x\to0$ it and only if $\lvert f(x)\rvert\to0$ as $x\to0$. In your case, making this very explicit, we have that
$$\lvert e^{-(1+i\xi)x}\rvert=\lvert e^{-x}e^{-i\xi x}\rvert=\lvert e^{-x}\rvert\lvert\cos(-\xi x)+i\sin(-\xi x)\rvert=e^{-x}\sqrt{\cos^2(-\xi x)+\sin^2(-\xi x)}=e^{-x}.$$
So $\lvert e^{-(1+i\xi)x}\rvert=e^{-x}\to0$ as $x\to\infty$.

Thank you, the missing piece for me was "$f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ if and only if $\lvert f(x) \rvert \to 0$ as $x \to 0$.

Since $e^{-(1+i\xi)x}=e^{-x}e^{-i\xi x}$ and $\lvert e^{-i\xi x}\rvert =1$ you have:
$$0\le|e^{-(1+i\xi)x}|=|e^{-x}e^{-i\xi x}|= e^{-x}\to 0 $$
